# Seed - How reinitialize my seed - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I create this seed

```
rails = Course.create(title: "Ruby On Rails")
models = rails.chapters.create(title: "Models")

models.items << Lesson.create(title: "What is Active Record?", content: "Lesson content here")

models.items << Exercice.create(title: "The Active Record pattern", content: "Exo about active record pattern")
models.items << Exercice.create(title: "Object Relational Mapping", content: "Exo about ORM")
models.items << Exercice.create(title: "Active Record as an ORM Framework", content: "Exo about ORM")

models.items << Lesson.create(title: "Convention over Configuration in Active Record", content: "Lesson content here")

models.items << Exercice.create(title: "Naming Conventions", content: "Exo about naming convention")
models.items << Exercice.create(title: "Schema Conventions", content: "Exo about schema convention")

models.items << Lesson.create(title: "Model summary", content: "Lesson content here")

models.items << Exam.create(title: "Rails Models exam", content: "Exam content here")

puts "done"
```

I have done `rake db:seed`.

My controller Course is:

class CoursesController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @courses = Course.all
  end

  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

My controller Chapter is :

class ChaptersController < ApplicationController

```
  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @chapter = @course.chapters.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

My controller Chapter is :

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @chapter = @course.chapters.find(params[:chapter_id])
    @item = @chapter.items.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And in the app/views/courses/index.html.erb

```
<div class="container-page">
  <div class="padding-page">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="page-progress">
            <h1>
              Page en cours de réalisation
            </h1>

            <% @courses.each do |course| %>
            <h2>
            <%= link_to course.title, course %>

            </h2>
            <% end %>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it appears title courses numerous times and I want to have just see one time. How do I reset or destroy or hide the others courses wjich name the same Name and have the same structure?

[Here is the index iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCdbu.png)

If you want more informations I give you but tell me what can I do. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that there is other record exists in you `Course` model, do `Course.all` and then update your question with the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run `rake db:seed` multiple times? If that's the case, drop, create, migrate, seed your database again.

If in the future you need to update your seeds and re-run them, make sure you do not create multiple records. You can do that by changing your code, from that:

```
rails = Course.create(title: "Ruby On Rails")
models = rails.chapters.create(title: "Models")

models.items << Lesson.create(title: "What is Active Record?", content: "Lesson content here")
```

to that:

```
rails = Course.where(title: "Ruby On Rails").first_or_create
models = rails.chapters.where(title: "Models").first_or_create

models.items << Lesson.where(title: "What is Active Record?").first_or_create(title: "What is Active Record?", content: "Lesson content here")
```

Find the First Instance in the Table. If None Exists, Create One.

Comment: Thank you i understand what you mean. yes.